# how to change the format json response in wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf

i have create a wcf all is working but i need to change the format of the json response is end.

This is the response:

```
{"LoginResponseResult":{"responsecode":"1","responsemessage":"success","UserDetails":{"firstname":"aaa","lastname":"aaa"}}}
```

what i want to display

```
{"LoginResponse":{"responsecode":"1","responsemessage":"success","UserDetails":{"firstname":"aaa","lastname":"aaa"}}}
```

here is my class

```
namespace JSONWCF
{
    [DataContract]
    public class LoginResponse
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "responsecode", Order = 0)]
        public string Responsecode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember(Name = "responsemessage", Order = 1)]
        public string Responsemessage
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "UserDetails", Order = 2)]
        public UserDetails details
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


    }
    [DataContract]
    public class UserDetails
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "firstname", Order = 0)]
        public string Firstname
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember(Name = "lastname", Order = 1)]
        public string Lastname
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

why is that "loginresponse" is added with "result"?
can i remove it and how?

service contact

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "POST",
            UriTemplate = "LoginMobile",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        LoginResponse LoginResponse(Login LoginRequest);


public LoginResponse LoginResponse(Login LoginRequest)
        {
LoginResponse LoginResponse = new LoginResponse();
                        UserDetails details = new UserDetails();
                        details.Firstname = "aaa";
                        details.Lastname = "aa";
                        LoginResponse.details = details;
                        LoginResponse.Responsecode = "1";
                        LoginResponse.Responsemessage = "success";
                        return LoginResponse;}
```

Comment: Maybe `[DataContract(Name = "LoginResponse")]`?

Comment: not working still the same output

Comment: I have a solution. Please share your ServiceContract class

Comment: i updated the post please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change the ServiceContract as follows

`[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "POST",
            UriTemplate = "LoginMobile",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        LoginResponse LoginResponse(Login LoginRequest);`

It will return something like this
`{"responsecode":"1","responsemessage":"success","UserDetails":{"firstname":"aaa","lastname":"aaa"}}`

I assume you do not need to use `LoginResponseResult` or `LoginResponse` anyway.

What is the problem that you are facing at the client side? Simply use your service with ChannelFactory, you should not face any issues.

I think because if you use `WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`, WCF Rest engine automatically appends a `Result` to the returning JSON when it is being wrapped and we might not have control over it.

Comment: is there anyway i could LoginResponse?

Comment: I don't think you will have a control over that without doing a lot of overriding etc. Believe me, you don't want to go there just to remove `Result` string from the JSON.